# Why **Excursion length** is less than **Denominator**?

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

Can anyone prove that the **Excursion length** of any fraction's decimal representation which is cyclic, is less than its **Denominator**?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider $\frac17$ as an example. Successive digits of this fraction are determined by division with remainder. Since 7 does not fit into 1, we start with
$$
0.
$$
with a remainder of 1. Then for the second digit, we multiply this remainder by 10, giving 10, and repeating: 7 fits into 10 once, with remainder 3. We obtain
$$
0.1
$$
and we repeat. 7 fits into 30 four times, with remainder 2; into 20 twice, with remainder 6; into 60 eight times, with remainder 4; into 40 five times, with remainder 5; and into 50 seven times with remainder 1. This gives
$$
0.142857
$$
and now we are back to the start of remainder 1. Thus the number starts repeating. The repeating part could never have been longer than 7, because there are only 7 remainders to cycle through: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. And in fact, the cycle always had to be *less* than 7, because if the remainder 0 ever occurs, then the fraction just terminates (which gives cycle length 1), so the remainders can only really cycle through 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Now, the same works for $\frac mn$ for any $m > 0, n > 1$.

Comment: Thank you but how about if all digits less than m occurs in decimal representation and still we dont obtain cycle? for example we obtain a number like 1234513?

Comment: The cycle is not in the digits, it is in the remainders. Once you reach an earlier *remainder*, the sequence of *remainders* also repeats. That means in particular that the sequence of digits starts cycling; but the sequence of digits could have repeats earlier.